# recursion linked list ? I think

Tags: c

I am very new and I have trouble understanding the macro steps I need to learn how to effectively code. These assignments feel extremely abstract and have to learn everything about recursion before I can even do it. Coding up a program is not easy, and I do really well when someone "helps me stay between the mayonnaise and mustard" so to speak. What am I doing wrong and what direction do I need to continue in?

I was thinking that I needed to sort the list first then have two seperate functions for merge sort and insertion sort per the assignment:

> You are spending most of your time at home in this pandemic. It is of most importance for people to be aware of where other people, who
> are infected with COVID-19 are, and who they've been near.  Keeping
> track  of  this  information  is  known  as  "contact  tracing."
> You've  heard  that  there might  be  some  very  high  paying  jobs
> if  you  can  show  your  contract  tracing  skills  to  the
> government, so you've decided to write a little program to highlight
> those skills.Your area can be modeled on the Cartesian plane. You are
> located at the point (x, y). In addition, you  have  the  Cartesian
> coordinates  of  all  people  currently  infected  with  COVID-19.
> What  you would  like  to  do  is  write  a  program  that  sorts
> these  locations  based  on their  distance  from  you, followed by
> handling queries. The queries are of the form of a point you are
> thinking of visiting. Your program should identify if someone who is
> infected is at that location, and if so, what their rank  is  on  the
> sorted  list  of  infected  people.  If  no  one  is  infected  at
> that  location,  you  should correctly identify this.
>
> Note: There are many important implementation restrictions for this assignment, so to make sure everyone reads these, the section on
> implementation restrictions will be next, changing the order of the
> sections as compared to other assignments.
>
> **Implementation Restrictions**
>
> 1. You must use a specified combination of Merge Sort and Insertion Sort to sort the point data. Specifically, for each input
>    case, a threshold value, t, will be given. If the subsection of the
>    array to sort has t or fewer values to sort, Insertion Sort should be
>    used. Otherwise, Merge Sort should be used.Further details about the
>    comparison used for the sorting are below.
> 2. You must store your coordinates in a struct that contains two integer fields.
> 3. You  must  write  a  function compareTo which  takes  in  two  pointers,  ptrPt1  and  ptrPt2,  to coordinate structs and returns a
>    negative integer if the point pointed to by ptrPt1 is closer to you
>    than the point pointed to by ptrPt2, 0 if the two locations pointed to
>    by both are identical locations, and a positive integer if the point
>    pointed to by ptrPt1 is farther from you than the point pointed to by
>    ptrPt2. Exceptions to this will be when the two pointers are pointing
>    to points that are the same distance  from  you,  but  are  distinct
>    points.  In  these  cases,  if  ptrPt1's  x  coordinate  is  lower
>    than ptrPt2's x coordinate, a negative integer must be
>    returned.Alternatively, if ptrPt1's x coordinate is greater than
>    ptrPt2's x coordinate a positive integer must be returned. Finally, if
>    the x coordinate of both points is the same, if ptrPt1's y coordinate
>    is lower than ptrPt2's y coordinate, a negative integer  must be
>    returned. If ptrPt1's  y coordinate  is greater than ptrPt2's  y
>    coordinate, a positive integer must be returned.
> 4. Since your location must be used for sorting, please make the variable that stores your x and y coordinates global. Your program
>    should have no other global variables.
> 5. A Binary Search function must
>    be used when answering queries.
> 6. Your sort function should take in
>    the array to be sorted,the  length of the array as well as the
>    threshold value, t, previously  mentioned. This  function should NOT
>    be recursive. It should be a wrapper function.
> 7. The  recursive  sort
>    function  (you  can  call  this  mergeSort)  should  take  in  the
>    array,  a  starting index into the array, an ending index into the
>    array and the threshold value t. In this function, either recursive
>    calls should be made OR a call to an insertion sort function should be
>    made.
>
> **The Problem**
>
> Given your location, and the location of each person who has COVID-19, sort the list by distance from  you  from  shortest to
> longest,  breaking  ties  by  x-coordinate  (lower  comes  first),
> and  then breaking those ties by y coordinate (lower comes
> first). After sorting, answer several queries about points in the
> coordinate plane. Specifically, determine if a query point contains
> someone who is infected or not. If so, determine that person's ranking
> on the sorted list in distance from you.
>
> **The Input(to be read from standard input)-Your Program Will Be Tested on Multiple Files**
>
> The
> first line of the input contains 5 integers separated by spaces. The
> first two of these values are x and y (|x|, |y| ≤ 10000), representing
> your location. The third integer is n (2 ≤ n ≤ 106), representing the
> number of infected people. The fourth integer is s (1 ≤ s ≤ 2x105),
> representing the number of points  to  search  for.  The  last
> integer, t (1 ≤ t≤ 30),  represents  the  threshold  to  be  used  for
> determining whether you run Merge Sort of Insertion Sort. The next
> n lines of the input contain x and y coordinate values, respectively,
> separated by spaces, representing the locations of infected people.
> Each of these values will be integers and the points will be distinct
> (and also different from your location) and the absolute value of x
> and y for all of these coordinates will not exceed 10,000.Then the
> next s lines of the file contains x and y coordinate values for
> searching. Both values on each line will be integers with an absolute
> valueless than or equal to 10,000.
>
> **The Output (to be printed to standard out)**
>
> The  first n lines  of  output  should  contain  the  coordinates  of  the  people  infected,
> sorted  as previously mentioned. These lines should have the
> x-coordinate, followed by a space, followed by the y-coordinate.The
> last s lines of output will contain the answers to each of the s queries
> in the input. The answer for a single query will be on a line by
> itself. If the point queried contains an infected person, output a
> line with the following format:
>
> ```
> x y found at rank R
> ```
>
> , where (x, y) is the
> query point, and R is the one-based rank of that infected person in
> the sorted list. (Thus, R will be 1 more than the array index in which
> (x, y) is located, after sorting.) If the point queried does NOT
> contain an infected person, output a line with the following format:
>
> ```
> x y not found
> ```
>
> **Sample Input**
>
> (Note: Query points in blue for clarity. last five)
>
> ```
> 0 0 14 5 53
> 1 -6 
> -2 -4 
> 3 4 
> -4 2 
> 4 -1 
> 3 2 
> 2 0 
> -5 -4 
> -2 -6 
> 6 4 
> 4 -2 
> 4 0 
> 5 -4 
> 6 2 
> -13 1  
> 0 -5
> ```

my code so far

```
#include <stdio.h>

int x = 0;//global coordinates
int y = 0;

typedef struct {
    int xInput, yInput;
}coordinates;

void scanPoints(coordinates[], int infectedPeople);
void scanSearchValues(coordinates[], int pointsToSearch);

void SortPoints(coordinates[], int);
int lessThan(coordinates[], int, int);
void printPoints(coordinates[], int);

void
scanPoints(coordinates pts[], int infectedPeople){
    for (int i = 0; i < infectedPeople; i++){
        scanf("%d %d", &pts[i].xInput, &pts[i].yInput);
    }
}

void
scanSearchValues(coordinates pts[], int pointsToSearch){
    for (int i = 0; i < pointsToSearch; i++){
    scanf("%d %d", &pts[i].xInput, &pts[i].yInput);
    }
}

void
sortPoints(coordinates pts[], int infectedPeople){
  
    int i, start, min_index, temp;

    for (start = 0; start < infectedPeople - 1; start++) {
    min_index = start;

    for (i = start + 1; i < infectedPeople; i++) {
    if (lessThan(pts, i, min_index)) {
    min_index = i;
    }
    }

    if (min_index != start) {
    coordinates temp = pts[start];
    pts[start] = pts[min_index];
    pts[min_index] = temp;
    }
    }
}

int
lessThan(coordinates pts[], int p, int q) {

if ((pts[p].xInput < pts[q].xInput) || ((pts[p].xInput == pts[q].xInput) && (pts[p].yInput < pts[q].yInput))) {
return 1;
    }
}




int
main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    
    int infectedPeople;
    int pointsToSearch;
    int threshold;
   
    scanf("%d%d", &x, &y);
    if(x > 10000 || y > 10000 )
        return 0;

    scanf("%d", &infectedPeople);
    if(infectedPeople < 2 || infectedPeople > 1000000)
        return 0;
   
    scanf("%d", &pointsToSearch);
    if(pointsToSearch < 1 || pointsToSearch > 200000)
        return 0;
    
    scanf("%d", &threshold);
    if(threshold < 1 || threshold > 30)
        return 0;
    
    
    return 0;
    
}
```

Comment: "What am I doing wrong ...?" What makes you think that you are doing something wrong. Please describe the behaviour and compare it to the required behaviour.

Comment: `Query points in blue for clarity.last five` ???

Comment: Please read [*Introduction to algorithms*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Introduction_to_Algorithms), [*Modern C*](https://modernc.gforge.inria.fr/), [*How to debug small programs*](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: if I were to describe my behavior it would be running around acting like the end of the world because of how complicated learning coding is. While I am suppose to just osmosis the information. The disparity in skill in class is huge. I find myself having trouble on the conceptual stuff like mapping out a plan. like how to know what functions are needed and which are not. thank you for the help.

Comment: the blue or suppose to be blue query points are the last five points there that I need to use to search the rest of the list.

Answer (score 4):

This is a challenging exercise for someone new to programming, but the first step is to read the problem description carefully.  It might help to print it out on paper, so that you can easily mark it up with highlighter and / or pen.  Additionally, you may be intimidated by all the details specified in the exercise.  *Don't be!* Although some make work for you, most make *decisions* for you.  The latter kind save you work, and do you exactly the service you asked of us: help you stay on track.

One of the keys to programming is learning to divide a problem into smaller pieces.  Sometimes those pieces will also need to be divided into even smaller pieces.  Many of these pieces will correspond naturally to functions, and accordingly, a second key to programming is recognizing how to choose the pieces so that they have well-defined inputs and outputs, and, to some extent, so that pieces can be re-used.  In your case, the overall problem statement gives you a starting point for performing such an analysis:

> **Given** your location, and the location of each person who has COVID-19,
> **sort the list** by distance from you from shortest to longest, breaking ties by x-coordinate (lower comes first), and then breaking
> those ties by y coordinate (lower comes first). After sorting, **answer
> several queries** about points in the coordinate plane. Specifically,
> determine if a query point contains someone who is infected or not. If
> so, determine that person's ranking on the sorted list in distance
> from you.

(Emphasis added.)  The three main pieces I see there are

- read and store input data
- sort the data
- analyze the result and produce output

#### Reading the input

The implementation restrictions in the problem description have a lot to say about how you read and store the data.  In particular,

> 2. You must store your coordinates in a struct that contains two integer fields.

You've prepared such a structure type.

> 4. Since your location must be used for sorting, please make the variable that stores your x and y coordinates global. Your program should have no other global variables.

Reading the restrictions carefully, I think the expectation is that you use the coordinates structure to represent *all* coordinates appearing in the program, including the (one) global variable representing your own coordinates.

> 6. Your sort function should take in **the array** to be sorted

You mentioned a linked list, but this indicates that you are expected to store the data in an array, not a linked list.  From my more experienced vantage point, I have more reasons to believe that that is the expectation.

The detailed description of the input format gives you additional guidance on how to perform the reading, as of course the code needs to be suited to the data.  So, read the first line of input to get the main program parameters, and store them appropriately.  Among those is the number of infected person records to read; you'll need to store all those in memory in order to sort them and answer multiple queries about them, so allocate an array of structs large enough to hold them, then proceed to read those data.

You could similarly read and store the queries in advance, but I would suggest instead performing the required sorting first, and then processing each query immediately after reading it, without storing the whole list of queries.

#### Sorting the data

You write,

> I was thinking that I needed to sort the list first then have two seperate functions for merge sort and insertion sort

Yes, I too read the problem description to be asking for separate merge sort and insertion sort functions -- and that's not what you seem presently to be providing.  It also asks for a wrapper function that accepts the input and passes it on to the appropriate sort implementation, either (recursive) merge sort or insertion sort.  Note that the wrapper function does not itself sort the list, except inasmuch as it passes the list to one of the other functions for sorting:

```
void sortCoordinates(coordinates coords[], int count, int threshold) {
    if (/* your condition here */) {
        insertionSortCoordinates(coords, count);
    } else {
        mergeSortCoordinates(coords, count);
    }
}
```

(The names and most of the details of these particular functions are at your discretion.)

Additionally, the restrictions help you out again here, though you need to read between the lines a bit.  Both sorting and searching require that you have a way to compare the objects in the list, and look! The restrictions tell you exactly what form that should take:

> 3. You must write a function compareTo which takes in two pointers, ptrPt1 and ptrPt2, to coordinate structs [...]

In other words,

```
int compareTo(coordinates *ptrPt1, coordinates *ptrPt2) {
    /* your code here */
}
```

Your insertion and merge sort functions and also your binary search function (see below) will compare structures (when needed) by calling that function.

Do pay careful attention to the restrictions, though, as one of the decisions they make for you is the name for this function: `compareTo`, not `lessThan`.  Deviating from the restrictions in this regard would likely cost you some marks.

#### Computing the output

Whether you read and store the query lines in advance or process them as you read them (having first sorted the input), the main computation to be performed is a binary search of the coordinates, per restriction 5.  You'll wan't a function for that, maybe

```
int binarySearch(coordinates *target, coordinates coords[]) {
    /* your code here: returns 1-based rank if found, zero if not found */
}
```

Again, this function will use your `compareTo` function to compare coordinate structures.  Note in particular that if implemented correctly according to the restrictions, `compareTo()` will return zero if and only if the two objects being compared are equal.

Comment: thank you. I guess i was confused. I thought I needed to sort the list first from smallest to largest then once that was done depending on the threshold number use merge sort or insertion sort to find the queries of coordinates?Also, the compare to function is just and if statement etc comparing the two strings?

Comment: @help_stuck89, once the list is sorted in a particular order, it provides no additional benefit to sort it again in the same order.  Sorting it *once* (according to whichever algorithm is indicated by the list size and threshold value)  will support *all* the queries.

Comment: @help_stuck89, per restriction 3, the `compareTo` function operates on coordinate structures, not on the original input strings.  It is specified in considerable detail how the result is to be based on comparisons of *x* and *y* coordinates.  Comparison of the raw input strings -- if they were even available at that point -- would not produce the same result.

Comment: I read that paragraph and it is super confusing. I am not sure what he was going for. Like explaining it in so much detail it is difficult to follow. I will continue to study it.

Comment: "Reading the restrictions carefully, I think the expectation is that you use the coordinates structure to represent all coordinates appearing in the program, including the (one) global variable representing your own coordinates." what do you mean by this. How was I not doing this? or do you mean that there needs to be two sets of global variables one for the starting location and the other for the inputs?

Comment: @help_stuck89, restriction 3 is lengthy, but that's because it is pretty much an outline of the required implementation.  You don't necessarily need to digest the whole thing at once -- just start coding the first bits, and add each remaining piece in turn.  As for the global variables, you have file-scope variables named `x` and `y`.  That is two variables of type `int`, whereas the problem seems to demand instead one variable of type `coordinates`.

Answer (score 2):

in

```
int
lessThan(coordinates pts[], int p, int q) {

if ((pts[p].xInput < pts[q].xInput) || ((pts[p].xInput == pts[q].xInput) && (pts[p].yInput < pts[q].yInput))) {
return 1;
    }
}
```

if `((pts[p].xInput < pts[q].xInput) || ((pts[p].xInput == pts[q].xInput) && (pts[p].yInput < pts[q].yInput)))` is false the function does not return, introducing an undefined behavior in *sortPoints*

you wanted

```
int lessThan(coordinates pts[], int p, int q)
{
  return ((pts[p].xInput < pts[q].xInput) || ((pts[p].xInput == pts[q].xInput) && (pts[p].yInput < pts[q].yInput)));
}
```

---

in *sortPoints* the variable *temp* in `int i, start, min_index, temp;` is useless, remove it

---

In *main* you only read the 5 values, nothing more, so the other functions are useless, and you do not print nor compute something

---

Not sure my answer is really usefull ...